# SharePoint- Designer Workflow 2007 Copy List Item Issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a simple workflow designed to copy a list item from target list to a task list:

- Action Items- (where item is copied from)
- Action Item Tasks- (where item is copied to)

Problem is it only copies the item if an admin adds a new item to the list (Action Items).

How can I get the list item copied to the target for contributors also?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The site is located on public domain, but the alternate access mapping didn't include 'https' for URL protocols.